# APN not saving with EE Orange UK SIM on Kitkat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lg-g2, apn

I have an LG G2 rooted, running Android 4.4.2. I've put my existing EE Orange UK SIM in, and there are no APNs listed. Whenever I try and add the [EE settings](http://ee.co.uk/help/mobile-and-home-connections/checking-and-improving-your-network-coverage/our-network/changing-your-apn-settings#orange) and then save them, the APN list remains blank. How can I add my carriers APN settings?

I have tried:

1. Installing APN backup & restore app, setting as a system app in Titanium Backup and moving to the priv-app folder. Then deleting all APNs, resetting the phone. Still can't add an APN.
2. Creating a basic APN record, without all of the settings. That saves so that I can see it in APN list screen but when I update the record to include all of the settings it disappears again.
3. Looking at the apns-conf.xml file. There are loads of settings in here, but I'm not sure what this file does.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [service provided by WDS](http://setuporange.wdsglobal.com/internet) (Wireless Data Services Ltd, a Xerox company) where you can enter your model details and phone number, and it will send an SMS to setup the EE/Orange APN.